# What's the best way to set 'deep' configuration options?

Tags: c++, perl, matlab, configuration

Assume there is a function that requires a configuration setting as an input, but this function is called several levels deep from the top-level 'main' function.

What's the best way, in terms of best programming practices, to pass this setting to the function?

One way is to just use a global variable and set that at the top level function and read it in the target function, but I assume that that is considered bad programming practice.

Another way is to pass the setting as an argument all the way from the top, through the several intermediate functions, all the way down to the final target function. This seems very tedious though and perhaps error-prone.

Are there other approaches?

You can use your language of choice for your answer, but FYI, I'm using C/C++, Perl, and Matlab.

Comment: R has a nice `...` that can be passed on down with zero effort.

Comment: Why does the top-level function know that a very deeply nested function needs those configuration options?

Comment: "Real systems have no top" - Bertrand Meyer

Comment: @Xeo: Say the nested function is 'generate_signal' and it generates a different type of signal depending on whether this is a GSM or CDMA simulation. How will the nested function know that this is a GSM or CDMA simulation? This information is usually known at the top level of the simulation. If there are better ways of going about this, it would be interesting to hear about them.

Answer (score 3):

I like [singleton objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for configuration. It's a shared resource that should only ever have one instance. When you try to create a new object, you get the existing one. You don't worry about global variables or subroutine or method parameters. Simply get a new configuration object and use it as long as you need it.

There's an example in Gang of Four for C++.

Comment: Damn. I got distracted to feed the kids for 15 mins and you scooped the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Leave the procedural programming style with deep call stacks behind and the answer becomes a banality.

Remodel your program to take advantage of modern object-orientation. [Perl roles make for flat hierarchies.](http://use.perl.org/~Ovid/journal/38785) A configuration is then just an attribute.

Comment: No matter what programming style one uses, aren't there always some top-level parameters that need to be used by everyone? In my example from a comment above, say that you are running a simulation for either a GSM or CDMA system. All the functions and/or objects in the system need to be told that this is either a GSM or CDMA simulation. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: There's probably ways that you could always have global variables, but there are ways to accomplish the same things without them too. They are not necessary in many languages.

Answer (score 1):

A system I work with uses a Publish-Subscribe (Observer Pattern) implementation to propagate settings/configuration changes to objects that need to know about them.

The object (Subscriber, or Observer in the [original Gang of Four description](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx)) that needs to be notified of settings changes:

1. Inherits from Subscriber.
2. Attaches itself (subscribes) to the Publisher via the Publisher's Attach method.
3. Is notified by the Publisher whenever settings/configuration changes occur.

We use a [variant that allows Subscribers to poll Publishers](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/patterns/article.php/c837) for settings/configuration data on demand.

Using the Publish-Subscribe pattern minimizes coupling between the object that manages the settings, and the objects that need them.

Answer (score 0):

In matlab, I always have a script allParam.m, where I set all the parameters.

If a function needs one of those parameters, I just call the script, and it is set.